# Letter E Asterisk in java horizontal and vertical

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to java program and need to write program for secondary school (non-programmer) to print the letter E two times in horizontal way and vertical way.

Horizontal way

```
*****      *****
*          *
*****      *****
*          *
*****      *****
```

Vertical way

```
*****
*
*****
*
*****

*****
*
*****
*
*****
```

My java code now print only one letter E, please help how to write both ways

```
public class tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****" : "*";
            System.out.println(print);       
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, that's not the way how this site works. We'll not do your homework. Think about the task and apply the principles you learned at school. Come back when you have  a specific issue.

Comment: Hint: You might want nested `for` loops. `for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) { for (int j=0; j < 2; j++) {...}}`. And the other way around for vertical.

Answer (score 0):

use second for loops for multiple E, something like this

```
public class tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 int numberOfE = 3;
 for(int j=0; j< numberOfE ; j++) {
 for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****" : "*";
        System.out.println(print);       
 }
 System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

for horizontal

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            String print = i % 2 == 0 ? "*****    " : "*        ";
            for(int j=0; j< numberOfE ; j++) {
                System.out.print(print);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: it prints only vertical and not horizontal way.

Comment: @rabikmakani use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println() at last line

Comment: @mohsenJsk - if i use System.out.print(), eclipse gives - The method print(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments ()